# Quart Render-Template Website don't look good on some devices

Tags: python, html, css, quart

I currently have a quart endpoint in Python.
Via this endpoint the Index.html is rendered and filled with data.
Problem: On my PC I see the page normally, but on mobile it looks like this: [mobile look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lV8Wy.jpg)

and on desktop it looks like this:
[desktop look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txa5T.jpg)

Also, a friend tested and he only saw it after reloading several times.

Does anyone know a solution?

Thanks in advance!

I would expect it to look exactly the same from a design perspective.

Quart-Route:

```
@app.route('/test')
async def render_html_test():
    # Holen Sie die Nachricht aus der session und löschen Sie sie dann
    success = session.pop('success', None)
    error = session.pop('error', None)
    username = session.get('username')
    role = session.get('role')
    avatar = None  # Setzen Sie einen Standardwert für avatar
 
    if session.get('logged_in'):
        user_info = await get_discord_user_info(session['access_token'])
        if user_info and 'id' in user_info and 'avatar' in user_info:
            avatar = f"https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/{user_info['id']}/{user_info['avatar']}.png"
    return await render_template('/test_parts/index.html', username=username, success=success, error=error, avatar=avatar, role=role)
```

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js" lang="de">
<!--<![endif]-->

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="Chaosgaming Webseite">
    <meta name="author" content="Lukas W.">

    <title>Chaosgaming | Dein Gaming-Netzwerk</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='/images/favicon.png') }}">

    <!-- Vue.js CDN -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='/test_parts/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='/test_parts/assets/css/animate.min.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='/test_parts/assets/css/fontawesome.min.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='/test_parts/assets/css/line-awesome.min.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='/test_parts/assets/css/odometer.min.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='/test_parts/assets/css/venobox.min.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='/test_parts/assets/css/swiper.min.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='/test_parts/assets/css/header.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='/test_parts/assets/css/elements.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='/test_parts/assets/css/main.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='/test_parts/assets/css/responsive.css') }}">
    <!--jQuery Lib-->
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='test_parts/assets/js/vendor/jquary-3.6.0.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='test_parts/assets/js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3-respond-1.4.2.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='test_parts/assets/js/vendor/jquery.ajaxchimp.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='test_parts/assets/js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='test_parts/assets/js/vendor/popper.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='test_parts/assets/js/vendor/odometer.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='test_parts/assets/js/vendor/waypoints.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='test_parts/assets/js/vendor/venobox.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='test_parts/assets/js/vendor/swiper.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='test_parts/assets/js/vendor/smooth-scroll.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='test_parts/assets/js/vendor/wow.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='test_parts/assets/js/contact.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='test_parts/assets/js/main.js') }}"></script>

    <style>
        .message-box {
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            right: 10px;
            padding: 10px;
            border-radius: 8px;
            transition: opacity 0.3s;
        }

        .error-box {
            background-color: #ff4c4c;
            color: white;
        }

        .success-box {
            background-color: #4caf50;
            color: white;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <div v-if="isErrorVisible" class="message-box error-box">
            <p>{{ error }}</p>
            <button @click="closeError" class="close-button">X</button>
        </div>
        <div v-if="isSuccessVisible" class="message-box success-box">
            <p>{{ success }}</p>
            <button @click="closeSuccess" class="close-button">X</button>
        </div>

        <!--[if lt IE 8]>
            <p class="browserupgrade">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->

        <div class="site-preloader">
            <div class="spinner"></div>
        </div>
        <!--site preloader-->

        <header class="header">
            <div class="primary-header">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="primary-header-inner">
                        <div class="header-logo">
                            <a href="index.html">
                                <img class="logo" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='/images/Chaosgaming-Corporate.png') }}" width="80px" height="80px" alt="Logo">
                            </a>
                        </div><!-- /.header-logo -->
                        <div class="header-menu-wrap">
                            <ul class="nav-menu">
                                <li class="active"><a href="/">Startseite</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Services</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="/sessionFinder">Session-Finder</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="/kontakt">Kontakt</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div><!-- /.header-menu-wrap -->
                        <div class="header-right">
                            <div class="header-menu-wrap">
                                <ul class="nav-menu">
                                    <li v-if="!username"><a class="default-btn" href="/discord_login">Anmelden</a></li>
                                    <li v-else>
                                        <a v-if="isMobile" href="#">{{ username }}</a>
                                        <a v-else class="default-btn" href="#">{{ username }}</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="/profil">Profil</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="/service-portal">Service-Portal</a></li>
                                            <li v-if="role === 'Admin' || role === 'Mod' || role === 'Test-Mod'"><a href="/teambereich">Team-Bereich</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="/logout">Abmelden</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Burger menu -->
                            <div class="mobile-menu-icon">
                                <div class="burger-menu">
                                    <div class="line-menu line-half first-line"></div>
                                    <div class="line-menu"></div>
                                    <div class="line-menu line-half last-line"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- /.header-right -->
                    </div><!-- /.primary-header-one-inner -->
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.primary-header -->
        </header><!-- /.site-header-->

        <section class="hero-section">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="hero-content">
                    <h4>Chaosgaming<br> Discord-Server</h4>
                    <h1>Dein Knotenpunkt zur<br> Virtuellen Welt!</h1>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <a href="/discord" class="default-btn">Discord-Server beitreten</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="hero-element">
                        <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='/test_parts/assets/img/game-charecters.png') }}" alt="thumb">
                        <div class="shape-wrap">
                            <div class="shape shape-1"></div>
                            <div class="shape shape-2"></div>
                            <div class="shape shape-3"></div>
                            <div class="shape shape-4"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="shape-wrap right">
                            <div class="shape shape-1"></div>
                            <div class="shape shape-2"></div>
                            <div class="shape shape-3"></div>
                            <div class="shape shape-4"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- /.hero-element -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="gradiant-border"></div>
        </section>
        <!--/.hero-section  -->

        <section class="team-section padding-bottom">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="section-heading text-center mb-40 wow fade-in-bottom" data-wow-delay="200ms">
                    <h2>Unser <span>Team</span></h2>
                    <p>Our success in creating business solutions is due in large part <br>to our talented and highly
                        committed team.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="outside-spacing">
                    <div class="team-carousel">
                        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                            <div class="swiper-slide">
                                <div class="team-item">
                                    <div class="team-thumb">
                                        <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='/test_parts/assets/img/team-1.png') }}" alt="thumb">
                                        <div class="shape-wrap">
                                            <div class="shape shape-1"></div>
                                            <div class="shape shape-2"></div>
                                            <div class="shape shape-3"></div>
                                            <div class="shape shape-4"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="team-content">
                                        <span class="whte-shape"></span>
                                        <h3><a href="player-details.html">@lukaswrn</a></h3>
                                        <h4>Admin</h4>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="swiper-slide">
                                <div class="team-item">
                                    <div class="team-thumb">
                                        <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='/test_parts/assets/img/team-2.png') }}" alt="thumb">
                                        <div class="shape-wrap">
                                            <div class="shape shape-1"></div>
                                            <div class="shape shape-2"></div>
                                            <div class="shape shape-3"></div>
                                            <div class="shape shape-4"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="team-content">
                                        <span class="whte-shape"></span>
                                        <h3><a href="player-details.html">@bananadany</a></h3>
                                        <h4>Admin</h4>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="swiper-slide">
                                <div class="team-item">
                                    <div class="team-thumb">
                                        <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='/test_parts/assets/img/team-3.png') }}" alt="thumb">
                                        <div class="shape-wrap">
                                            <div class="shape shape-1"></div>
                                            <div class="shape shape-2"></div>
                                            <div class="shape shape-3"></div>
                                            <div class="shape shape-4"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="team-content">
                                        <span class="whte-shape"></span>
                                        <h3><a href="player-details.html">@tf_lisa</a></h3>
                                        <h4>Admin</h4>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="swiper-slide">
                                <div class="team-item">
                                    <div class="team-thumb">
                                        <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='/test_parts/assets/img/team-2.png') }}" alt="thumb">
                                        <div class="shape-wrap">
                                            <div class="shape shape-1"></div>
                                            <div class="shape shape-2"></div>
                                            <div class="shape shape-3"></div>
                                            <div class="shape shape-4"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="team-content">
                                        <span class="whte-shape"></span>
                                        <h3><a href="player-details.html">@reyes45</a></h3>
                                        <h4>Test-Moderator</h4>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Carousel Arrows -->
                        <div class="swiper-nav swiper-next"><i class="las la-long-arrow-alt-right"></i></div>
                        <div class="swiper-nav swiper-prev"><i class="las la-long-arrow-alt-left"></i></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section> <!-- /.team-section -->

        <section class="contact-section padding-bottom">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row align-items-center">
                    <div class="col-md-6 sm-padding">
                        <div class="section-heading">
                            <h3>Send Us a Mail</h3>
                            <h2>Join Us As a Super Fans and Get all <span>the Benefits</span></h2>
                            <p>Our success in creating business solutions is due in large part <br>to our talented and
                                highly committed team.</p>
                            <a href="contact.html" class="default-btn">Join Our Team <span></span></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 sm-padding">
                        <div class="contact-form ml-40">
                            <form action="contact.php" method="post" id="ajax_contact" class="form-horizontal">
                                <div class="contact-form-group">
                                    <div class="form-field">
                                        <input type="text" id="contact_name" name="contact_name" class="form-control"
                                            placeholder="Your Name" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-field">
                                        <input type="email" id="contact_email" name="contact_email" class="form-control"
                                            placeholder="Email" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-field message">
                                        <textarea id="message" name="message" cols="30" rows="4" class="form-control"
                                            placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-field">
                                        <button id="submit" class="default-btn" type="submit">Send
                                            Massage<span></span></button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="form-messages" class="alert" role="alert"></div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section><!-- /.contact-section -->

        <div class="sponsor-section padding-bottom">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="outside-spacing">
                    <div class="sponsor-carousel">
                        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                            <div class="swiper-slide">
                                <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='/test_parts/assets/img/client-1.png') }}" alt="client">
                            </div>
                            <div class="swiper-slide">
                                <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='/test_parts/assets/img/client-2.png') }}" alt="client">
                            </div>
                            <div class="swiper-slide">
                                <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='/test_parts/assets/img/client-3.png') }}" alt="client">
                            </div>
                            <div class="swiper-slide">
                                <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='/test_parts/assets/img/client-4.png') }}" alt="client">
                            </div>
                            <div class="swiper-slide">
                                <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='/test_parts/assets/img/client-5.png') }}" alt="client">
                            </div>
                            <div class="swiper-slide">
                                <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='/test_parts/assets/img/client-6.png') }}" alt="client">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.sponsor-section -->
        
        <footer class="footer-section">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row footer-items">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 sm-padding">
                        <div class="footer-item">
                            <a class="brand" href="index.html"><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='/images/Chaosgaming-Corporate.png') }}" width="150px" height="150px" alt="logo"></a>
                            <p>Our success in creating business solutions is due in large part to our talented and highly
                                committed team.</p>
                            <ul class="social-list">
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 sm-padding">
                        <div class="footer-item footer-list">
                            <div class="widget-title">
                                <h3>Rechtliches</h3>
                            </div>
                            <ul class="footer-links">
                                <li><a href="upcoming-matches.html">Impressum</a></li>
                                <li><a href="faq-page.html">Datenschutzerklärung</a></li>
                                <li><a href="about.html">Nutzungsbedingungen</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 sm-padding">
                        <div class="footer-item">
                            <div class="widget-title">
                                <h3>Kontakt</h3>
                            </div>
                            <ul class="footer-contact">
                                <li><span>Discord:</span>chaosgaming.eu/discord</li>
                                <li><span>E-Mail:</span>info@chaosgaming.eu</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 sm-padding">
                        <div class="footer-item subscribe-wrap">
                            <div class="widget-title">
                                <h3>Newsletter Anmeldung</h3>
                            </div>
                            <form action="#" class="subscribe-form">
                                <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" required="">
                                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="mailchimpsubscribe">
                                <button class="submit">Anmelden</button>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                <div id="subscribe-result">
                                    <div class="subscription-success"></div>
                                    <div class="subscription-error"></div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="copyright-wrap">
                <div class="container">
                    <p>© <span id="currentYear"></span> ChaosGaming | Alle Rechte vorbehalten.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--copyright-wrap-->
        </footer>
        <!--footer-section-->
    </div>
    <div id="scrollup">
        <button id="scroll-top" class="scroll-to-top hover-target"><i class="las la-arrow-up"></i></button>
    </div>
    <!--scrollup-->


    
    <script>
            new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                error: "{{ error }}",
                success: "{{ success }}",
                username: "{{ username }}" !== "None" ? "{{ username }}" : null,
                avatar: "{{ avatar }}",
                role: "{{ role }}",
                isMobile: false
            },
            methods: {
                closeError: function () {
                    this.error = null;
                },
                closeSuccess: function() {
                    this.success = null;
                },
                checkWindowSize: function() {
                    this.isMobile = window.innerWidth <= 768; // oder jede andere Grenze, die Sie als "mobil" definieren möchten
                }
            },
            computed: {
                isErrorVisible: function () {
                    return this.error && this.error !== '' && this.error !== 'None';
                },
                isSuccessVisible: function() {
                    return this.success && this.success !== '' && this.success !== 'None';
                },
                created() {
                    this.checkWindowSize();
                    window.addEventListener('resize', this.checkWindowSize);
                },
                destroyed() {
                    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.checkWindowSize);
                },
            }
            });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: [responsive.css and main.css](https://pastebin.com/fy47HiuW)

Comment: I think you'd get a better answer if you isolated the html and css and then asked this question, as Quart plays no role in any difference seen here.